# How to use multiple Modals?

Tags: modal-verbs, syntax

Yesterday I was reading an article and I came across a sentence with two modals and I have never seen two modals together.

> The military might can curb the terrorist group.

Can anybody explain how to use two modals simultaneously?

Comment: Here, 'might' of military might is not a modal. It means 'power'.

Answer (score 1):

This usage is shown in this dictionary:
[Wiktionary "might can"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/might_can)
"(double modal / stacked modal, used in some dialects, chiefly Southern US) might be able to; be potentially able to"
*I might can go swimming in the creek tomorrow.*

For a language learner it might be better to avoid double modals, since their use is regional and informal.

Here are a couple of links I found searching for stacked or double modals:

[Yale.edu "multiple modals"](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/multiple-modals)
[Verblio "double modals"](https://www.verblio.com/blog/double-modals-descriptive-grammar)